# IIS7 not .html or .js files but serves .aspx

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to implement authentication into my website. I have managed to be correctly redirected to a login page when I try to access the secured website and I can login. However, the problem is that after login I can't access static files (such as .html, .css, .js, etc.), but I can access without any problems .aspx files.

I get error 500.0 with error code 0x80070542.

I have actually found very precise description of my problem [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2014/09/02/error-500-0-internal-server-error-authenticaterequest-staticfile-0x80070542.aspx), but the solution doesn't work for me (I already have IIS_IUSRS in there).

Has anybody experienced a similar problem? If you need to see parts of my web.config, let me know and I will add them.

Thanks

Comment: Recommend you carry out Failed Request Tracing to get to the bottom of the error http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis